# How do I add doubles from Strings in Strings Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I am currently trying to add the sums of all the doubles located in multiple strings in my strings array. I thought about splitting them like you can see in the screenshot but its not letting me. Can somebody please let me know what im doing wrong and if there is an easier way to go about it. Thanks :)

```
   package javaapplication3;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] testArray = new String [2];
        testArray[0] = "Part1: $10.00";
        testArray[1] = "Part2: $30.00";
        testArray[3] = "Part3: $50.00";
        Double [] array = new Double[testArray.length];
        for(int i=0;i<testArray.length;i++){

            //I want this to iterate through testArray[i], split every string by $, 
            //then store my doubles in array[i], so that I can add them and get total cost

            //In real project there are like 50 parts I need to add together.
           array[i] = Double.valueOf(testArray[i].split("$")[1]);  
        }
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:7)
C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: I did it says screen shot of my code

Comment: click the screenshot and you will see the image

Comment: `$` is a special character in regex, and you code will fail with `NullPointerException` once `i` reaches 2.

Comment: You have an array of length 3...but try to ref the 4th position which is 3

Comment: I know it's a screenshot and I know I can click it. Did you not understand the text about why **not** to do so???

Comment: Well that sucks...is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Doing what? Not post screenshots? Yes, it's called copy/paste. Of text, i.e. code and error message.

Comment: I meant about regex Andreas...sorry if I offended you by posting a screenshot.

Comment: Please 1) post your code as plain text (not an image), 2) tell us exactly what it is doing wrong 3) tell us exactly what you want it to do

Comment: @MichaelIsenhour Guess you're not sorry enough to click the edit link and *fix* the question, huh. --- And my previous comment was not me being offended. I'm not. It was me pointing out that your comment was unclear. --- But, you've already been told about 3(!) errors in the your code, so maybe you should just fix your code and delete the question.

Comment: As for your question about "another way to go about doing this", i.e. how to solve the regex problem, one obvious answer would be to **learn regex**, so you can escape the special character. --- But first, you should fix the error you currently have, as pointed out by Citizen Kane.

Comment: Hey Bohemian, I have strings in a string array and i need to iterate through each string in the array and add the doubles that are in with the text. I tried splitting the text from the doubles but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with indexing in your testArray. It's out of bound you have assigned it length three and you're adding a value to index 3 which is out of bound.
Arrays start from zero so if you have the size as 3 it means 0,1,2. And your have `testArray[3] = "Part 3: $ 50 "` which means you're assign out of bound. Do this instead `testArray [2] = "Part 3: 50"`.